# Can't compile packages with 'make'

Tags: makefile, compilation, solus

I've searched everywhere and can't find any solution to this. I've installed lts-headers and developer tools (system.devel). This happens to whatever I'm trying to compile.

Solus 4.9.43-39

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -std=c11 -O2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -c -o luksipc.o luksipc.c
In file included from /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h:1:0,
                 from /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/asm/errno.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/linux/errno.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/errno.h:35,
                 from luksipc.c:29:
/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h:1:31: error: #include nested too deeply
 #include <asm-generic/errno.h>
                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h:1:0,
                 from /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/asm/ioctls.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/bits/ioctls.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/sys/ioctl.h:26,
                 from luksipc.c:31:
/usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h:1:32: error: #include nested too deeply
 #include <asm-generic/ioctls.h>
                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h:1:0,
                 from /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/asm/ioctls.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/bits/ioctl-types.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/sys/ioctl.h:29,
                 from luksipc.c:31:
/usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h:1:32: error: #include nested too deeply
 #include <asm-generic/ioctls.h>
                                ^
make: *** [Makefile:27: luksipc.o] Error 1
```